# Argument out of Range Exception by using Calculated field

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

I have following Columdefs

```
   <Field ID="{64cd368d-2f95-4bfc-a1f9-8d4324ecb007}" Type="DateTime" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" Name="StartDate" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Start_Date;" Format="DateOnly" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="StartDate">
    <Default>[today]</Default>
  </Field>
  <Field Type="DateTime" ID="{cd21b4c2-6841-4f9e-a23a-738a65f99889}" Name="DueDate" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Due_Date;" Format="DateOnly" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="DueDate"></Field>
  <Field Type="Calculated" DisplayName="Dauer" ResultType="Number" ReadOnly="TRUE" ID="{f268d15f-a082-4bf4-833b-ca1691117cb4}" StaticName="Dauer" Name="Dauer" ColName="sql_variant1" RowOrdinal="0">
    <Formula>=DATEDIF([StartDate],[DueDate],"d")</Formula>
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef Name="DueDate" />
      <FieldRef Name="StartDate" />
    </FieldRefs>
  </Field>
```

With this definition i get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Here ist the full stack trace

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Das angegebene Argument liegt außerhalb des gültigen Wertebereichs.    bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCalculated.GetFieldValueAsTextOrHtml(Object value, Boolean asHtml)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.JSGrid.GridSerializer.LocalizeField(DataRow dr, GridField field, Object dataValue)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.JSGrid.GridSerializer.CreateLocalizedData(IEnumerable`1 unlocalizedSlicedRows)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.JSGrid.GridSerializer.BuildOutput()     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.JSGrid.GridSerializer.ToJson(Serializer s)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.JsonUtilities.Serializer.SerializeToJson(Object o)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.JSGrid.get_StartupScript()     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.JSGrid.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     bei System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     bei System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     bei System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart.RenderWebPart(HtmlTextWriter output)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartMobileAdapter.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     bei System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPChrome.RenderPartContents(HtmlTextWriter output, WebPart part)

When I remove the formular, it works very well. 
What can be the problem in there?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to encode your formula, in this example replace `"` with `&quot;`

```
<Formula>=DATEDIF([StartDate],[DueDate],&quot;d&quot;)</Formula>
```

Comment: thx for the suggestion, but the result is the same. :(

Comment: Strange, Have you tried setting it up in the GUI and then export the list as template. (Download and rename the file to name.cab). There you will see how SharePoint has constructed the XML for the field :)

Answer (score 0):

I think formulas use the display name rather than the internal name.

As I am a non-developer I am unsure looking at your script what the display names are but they seem to include underscores?